# I'm trying to do an if, but to no avail

Tags: arduino, logical-operators, arduino-c++

In the if (user == "A") code part {- It works, but if I put - if (user == '*') <- here is invisible, but it's an asterisk {- It won't, it goes through this if, and follows the code, I'm using a matrix keyboard in arduino ... I already gave a serial.print to see, the "*", responds on the keyboard but it won't.

```
void NovoUser() {
  lcd.clear();
  delay(10);
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
  lcd.print("***Novo Usuario***");
  String usuario = ler(1, "Digite seu usuario:", 1, false);
  bool existente = usuarioExistente(usuario);
  if (usuario == "A") {
    Serial.print(usuario);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Usuario invalido");
    delay(1000);
    NovoUser();
  } else {
    if (!existente) { /*existe*/
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("Usuario existente");
      delay(1000);
      existente = false;
      return NovoUser();
    } else {
      lcd.clear();
      String senha = ler(1, "Digite sua senha:", 4, false);
      if (incluiUsuario(usuario, senha)) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Usuario incluido");
        delay(1500);
        Menu();
      } else {
        lcd.setCursor(0, 4);
        lcd.print("erro");
        delay(2000);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should really program in English to avoid bilingual code...that's common practice. if it is an asterisk, why don't you check for one? what value is that symbol in ASCII table?

Comment: With ascii did not try, it is a good idea, I will do, thanks for the attention.